# Is a TypeError okay or should I use try/catch?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

I have this simple AJAX-Class which works as expected in all browsers except Internet Explorer <6 (which I don't care too much):

```
var Ajax = function(url, callback) {
    this.xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    this.xhr.open('GET', url, true);
    this.xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
            if (typeof callback === "function") {
                callback(this.responseText);
            }
        }
    }
    this.xhr.send();
};
```

So, my question is if there would be any reason or advantage to add `try/catch` to prevent a `TypeError` in IE<6? Like this:

```
    // ...
    try {
        this.xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    } catch(e) {
        return;
    }
    // ...
```

Or is it okay to risk this error? Does it prevent further code from being executed or displays an ugly warning or anything that kind?

Comment: i think you should use the `try-catch` block and gracefully handle the error.

Comment: I want to keep the code as short as possible. So I would only include `try/catch` if there was a real benefit to do so.

Comment: You shouldn't use try-catch if you don't plan to handle the error (`return;`) - a silent fail is seldom a good idea.